# Dynamic array allocation: .mexw64 is not a valid win32 application

Tags: c++, arrays, matlab

I am translating my C++ program into a MEX file. I am using the Matlab editor and compiling from the Matlab command window. My version of the Matlab is win64, and the compiler is minGW-w64. My structure of the file is as follows:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray * plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray * prhs[])
{
    RandomWalkMH_mex();
}
```

Where `RandomWalkMH_mex()` is the equivalent of `main()` in the original C++ program, and it calls all the other functions.

The file runs fine until I declare a dynamic 2D array in the function `RandomWalkMH_mex()`. The way I do the declaration is the same as the standard C++ declaration of an array:

```
void RandomWalkMH_mex(){

    ...

    double** parasim = new double*[nsim];
    for(int i = 0; i < nsim; ++i){
        parasim[i] = new double[npara];
    }

    ...

    for(int i = 0; i < nsim; ++i){
        delete [] parasim[i];
    }
    delete [] parasim;

    ...

}
```

The MEX file still compiles okay into a .mexw64 file, but when I test run the code by running `[y] = RandomWalkMH_mex(1000)` from the MATLAB Command Window, I get an error:

> Invalid MEX-file '...\RandomWalkMH_mex.mexw64': ....\RandomWalkMH_mex.mexw64 is not a valid Win32 application..

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening? I Googled for related answers but couldn't find one that solves my problem. I also looked into using the Dependency Walker, but I wasn't sure if it was useful for Windows 10..

Comment: `mexw64` is compiled for `x64` but you are trying to use it with your `x86` application apparently

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and sorry for being ignorant.. to my understanding, x64 is 64-bit, and x86 is 32-bit, is that correct? What I did was always to call the function from the MATLAB command line like this: [y] = RandomWalkMH_mex(1000). I was also kinda suspecting that putting in the dynamic array declaration somehow tricks MATLAB into thinking that it is 32-bit for some reason.. Could you suggest how I could fix this in some way..

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but note that you do not have a "2D array;" that would be contiguous in memory. What you have is an array of pointers to dynamically allocated arrays; a **much** less efficient data structure.

Comment: @Angew Thank you for the comment. I am very surprised, because when I Googled for how to declare a 2D dynamic array in C++, I found several tutorials that offered this solution. I will search again and see if I can find other solutions.

Comment: " I found several tutorials that offered this solution." - in other news, the internet is full of nonsense.

Comment: @NeilButterworth lol and those were solutions that came on top..

Comment: To put it straight: the generally best way to spell "dynamically-allocated array" (of any dimension) in C++ is `std::vector`, sized `width * height` (`* depth * ...`). If you're somehow too resource-constrained to use `vector`, use `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` instead. Do not meddle with naked `new`s.

Comment: @Angew Got it. I will look into them. Naked new's lol

Comment: @Angew It worked, thank you! Not only did the compiler stop complaining, but I learned to use vectors..